# HTML tags in breadcrumb

Tags: html, breadcrumb

I have a page title CO<sub>2</sub>. The title in the nav menu shows it fine but breadcrumb renders the HTML as text **CO<sub>2</sub>**.

Is there an easy way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tags are recognized in a `title` element by HTML rules (and by browser practice); they are indeed rendered as such. In principle, you can use special characters like “₂” SUBSCRIPT TWO U+2082 in a `title` element. You can even denote them using character references:

```
<title>CO&#x2082;</title>
```

However, only [some fonts support SUBSCRIPT TWO](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2082/fontsupport.htm), and it is quite possible that the rendering of `title` elements e.g. in a browser top bar or tab label uses a font that does not support to it. In that case, a rectangle, vertical bar, space, or other generic indicator of missing glyph probably appears.